# Disk brake rotor feels loose

Tags: mountain-bike, disc-brake, mechanical

Hey guys I've noticed my disk brake being "lose", I'm probably going to consult with LBS anyway but heres how I can describe it:

- the [rear] disk it self is not significantly more lose than the front one at least it wiggles the same amount (no excessive force was applied)
- no significant loss in braking power, same power when I pull the brake lever as before
- "activation point" hasnt changed aswell or at least not significantly for me to notice
- some softness but I havent changed them in like 250 km so they might have worn down alittle bit
- the wheel is mounted correctly so its not like the whole wheel is lose

My suspicion is that somehow the "brake gap" has widened somehow and need to be pulled together again.

**Brakes in question are:**

BRAKE   TEKTRO HD-M290, HYDRAULIC DISC BRAKE, ROTOR: 180/160MM

BRAKELEVERS TEKTRO HD-M290, HYDRAULIC DISC BRAKE

Comment: Check the tightness of the rotor bolts (usually TORX heads) or the lockring. Check the bolts of the callipers to the fork/ rear stay.

Comment: can I screw this somehow up ?

Comment: Dude. They're *bolts*. They screw in, they screw out. If they're loose, it should be obvious upon close examination.

Comment: okay will try, I will report back for an update

Comment: @zython you can screw it up by over tightening the bolt and shearing it off, and totalling the wheel. There is usually a torque setting printed on the rotor. if you don't have a torque wrench and are not used to working with bike parts take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future people who might have the same problem described:

---

Okay I have figured it out with the help of my local bikestore.

Turns out the whole wheel was a little bit lose.

After taking apart the wheel it turns out the so called locknut or what seemed like the lock nut  has untightend itself[image]

After taking off the casette and everything else in the way and after tightening the lock nut the problem was solved and the wheel back in place